# How to get hold of AutomatedInstallData within IzPack 5 InstallerListener methods?

Tags: izpack

I've tried to find any info on that but failed, maybe someone here can help.

I'm using IzPack 5 since couple of weeks and that's what I started with, so I have no prior IzPack 4 experience.

What I want to do is the following:

1. Give the user an opportunity to select data directory via
   UserInputPanel (works fine)
2. Validate the entry by checking if the
   database already resides there (works fine)
3. Depending on whether
   the DB already exists and if "force" flag specified on the
   UserInputPanel create the database after the packs have been
   installed

This last step, that's what I can't see how to do.

I hava a java class that implements InstallerListener interface:

```
public class IzPackInstaller implements com.izforge.izpack.api.data.DynamicInstallerRequirementValidator,
 com.izforge.izpack.api.event.InstallerListener {
```

It's the same class I use for both data validation / db existance check on step 2 and creation on step 3, just for convinience reasons, but it shouldn't matter

I override

```
@Override
public void afterInstallerInitialization(AutomatedInstallData data)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Called afterInstallerInitialization");
    System.out.println("db.location=" + data.getVariable("db.location"));
    System.out.println("db.force.creation=" + data.getVariable("db.force.creation"));
}
```

but it seems to be deprecated alltogether and is never called in runtime - checked with System.out's.
The same is valid for:

```
@Override
public void afterPacks(AutomatedInstallData data,
        AbstractUIProgressHandler handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Never called!");
}
```

I also override

```
@Override 
public void afterPacks(List<Pack> packs, ProgressListener listener) { }
```

which is called allright, but how to get hold of AutomatedInstallData within this method? Or how else can I read installer variables at this stage?

I thought of creating a singleton, which I would initialize with the variables during DynamicInstallerRequirementValidator.validateData() call and get the variables at a later point in time, but it's ugly and sounds like a nasty workaround - there should be a way to implement InstallerListener interface and be able to use the variables, shouldn't it?

I'd be really grateful for any hints...

Anton

Comment: Try to extend AbstractProgressInstallerListener with your listener which contains these methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, the behaviour is exactly the same, it's just that I don't have to override all the methods that I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very clean solution but there is a way to get a hold of AutomatedInstallData really anywhere in running izpack java without actually overriding some method etc. I would just not suggest it in the first place because it is a little tricky :)

```
public class Test {
  InstallerContainer container = new ConsoleInstallerContainer();
  AutomatedInstaller automatedInstaller = container.getComponent(AutomatedInstaller.class);
  AutomatedInstallData installData;

  public Test() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Field f = AutomatedInstaller.class.getDeclaredField("installData");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    installData = (AutomatedInstallData)f.get(automatedInstaller);
  }

  etc...
```

Now you will have access to the object AutomatedInstallData and its methods.